# How can I use multiple cores to process messages from SQS with Camel

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I am using Camel to read messages off an Amazon SQS queue, do some CPU-intensive processing, and then place them on another SQS queue. Camel is being invoked through the maven plugin, using `mvn camel:run`.

When run on a server with multiple cores, Camel only appears to be using a single core to process messages (as observed by monitoring CPU utilization of all cores). **How can I take advantage of all available cores?**

Things I have tried:

- Running multiple instances of the JVM (e.g. by running several `mvm camel:run` jobs in parallel). This works, but does not seem ideal.
- Setting the `maxMessagesPerPoll=10` on the consumer. Did not appear to make a difference.

The route in question:

```
     <route id="marctomods"  errorHandlerRef="eh">
        <from uri="aws-sqs://{{sqs.environment}}-normalize-marcxml?accessKey=${access.key}&amp;secretKey=${secret.key}&amp;amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=10" />
        <process ref="modsProcessor"/>
        <to uri="aws-sqs://{{sqs.environment}}-enrich?accessKey=${access.key}&amp;secretKey=${secret.key}&amp;amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient" />
     </route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally only get a single message in transit through a route. http://camel.apache.org/parallel-processing-and-ordering.html explains the parallel processing options.

You could, for example, read messages from sqs onto a seda queue and then have multiple parallel consumers reading from the seda queue, eg

```
<route>
    <from uri="aws-sqs://{{sqs.environment}}-normalize-marcxml />
    <to uri="seda:myQueue">
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="seda:myQueue?concurrentConsumers=10" />
    <process ref="modsProcessor"/>
    <to uri="aws-sqs://{{sqs.environment}}-enrich>
</route>
```

Comment: This worked, although I also had to add maxMessagesPerPoll=10 on the SQS consumer to get the best results.